# Mulesoft: How can dataweave read data from a Mule Subquery?

Tags: mule

I am trying to pull data from SFDC & my query looks something like this:

```
   Select X,Y,(Select Z from OpportunityLine) from Opportunity;
```

Post this I am trying to use dataweave to map it to values.

```
      <dw:transform-message doc:name="Salesforce Opportunity Selection">
      <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
      %output application/json
      ---
      payload map {
      id                  : $.X,
      name                : $.Y,

      }]]></dw:set-payload>
      </dw:transform-message>
```

How can I grab values from my subquery into the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a alias in your sql like this:

```
Select X,Y,(Select Z from OpportunityLine) FOO from Opportunity;
```

then you can access FOO in your dataweave:

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Salesforce Opportunity Selection">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    id: $.X,
    name: $.Y,
    foo: $.FOO
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

you can read more about aliases in sql [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm).

Comment: you will have to reference it in your dataweave just like you did with `$.X` and `$.Y`... that is why i added `foo: $.FOO` in my answer